# How to print TCL run commands

Tags: tcl

How to print each TCL command I am running , ideally how can I customize this print ?

i.e :

`>> namespaceXY::commandXY`

I would like to print :

"-- Running :  namespaceXY::commandXY"

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When source a Tcl script in Tcl shell, how can I let Tcl print every Tcl command inside the script to the shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63832193/when-source-a-tcl-script-in-tcl-shell-how-can-i-let-tcl-print-every-tcl-command)

Comment: Yes, I thought there is another solution other than "trace"...
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see a trace of commands, use an execution trace. You usually attach those to something like `source` or (less commonly) `eval`.

```
proc printTrace {commandCall op} {
    # I don't know whether you want the arguments too; they can get quite long...
    puts "-- Running : [lindex $commandCall 0]"
}
trace add execution source enterstep printTrace
source myScript.tcl
```

That will enable tracing of all commands from when the `source` starts to when it finishes; if that file includes your main loop processing, you'll get a print of absolutely everything.

Note that step-level execution tracing has a substantial overhead, and that some commands may have internal steps that you don't normally observe.

Comment: Yes I would like to print all the command as run in the script (with all given arguments), thanks

Comment: In that case, print the whole of `$commandCall`. And be aware that you'll get a lot of output.