# How to convert script into a hard coded version of it in Tcl language?

Tags: tcl, code-generation, interpretation, hardcoded

I am looking for a way to convert a script into its fully hard-coded version. I even don't know how this kind of function is named in software industry.. so I even don't know how to google it.  Here are some examples of what I want. I don't want to use any conditional or iterative function for the outputs.

Example 1)  foreach case

```
foreach x [list 1 2 3] { 
    puts "x=$x"
}
```

I'd like to convert this script to have:

```
puts "x=1" ; puts "x=2" ; puts "x=3"
```

Example 2)

```
set A 1
if { $A == "1" } {
    puts "A is 1"
} else {
    puts "A is not 1"
}
```

I want this to be :

```
set A 1
puts "A is 1"
```

Example 3) If I face comment line or unknown command or procedure, I just want to pass it to the output.

```
set argument 1000
UnknownProcedure $argement
```

This now should be :

```
set argument 100
UnknownProcedure 100
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some things _shouldn't or even can't_ be hard-coded like that, such as handles to open files. There's literally no promises at all that two runs will use the same channel names; the Tcl implementation is allowed to do anything it wants with them (and they're very much not repeatable on Windows).

Comment: This is the field of record/replay of program executions (for different purposes: debugging, testing, ...).

Answer (score 1):

You could try `trace add execution ...` to commands.  This is used to execute a body of code before the command itself if executed.  If you can pass the arguments of your command to your trace function and also use `info frame` to get the proc/command name being executed, then you could use the trace function to write out a hardcoded version of the command.

See here:

- https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/trace.htm
- https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/info+frame

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63832536/301832 for how you might use `trace add execution` (though in this case you wouldn't want to shorten the output)